# Should Groovy @CompileStatic classes still include metaclass code?

Tags: java, groovy, static-typing, groovy-eclipse, static-compilation

I'm starting to incorporate some Groovy classes into my Maven-built Spring application, primarily to reduce boilerplate on a lot of classes that are POJOs and value objects. (For comparison, I've been using Roo to handle the boilerplate, but Roo is getting increasingly flaky with newer versions of Spring and Maven.) One of my Spring Data MongoDB classes looks like this:

```
@Document
class ConcreteProcessingJob implements ImageAssetProcessingJob {

    @Id
    String id

    @Indexed(unique = true, sparse = true)
    String jobId

    @NotNull
    @Past
    Date started

    // more of the same
}
```

Since these are just run-of-the-mill struct objects, I don't need or want the complexity and overhead of Groovy's metaclassing and call-siting; I just want the equivalent to a POJO. I've tried annotating the classes with `@CompileStatic`, but while a couple of the calls in the bytecode have replaced `invokedynamic` with `invokevirtual`, I am still getting huge `.class` files with several large Groovy methods and data structures; one class that's nothing but an empty subclass that reifies a generic superclass is over 5k of bytecode.

I've compiled the code both from within Eclipse and from the command line, using the `groovy-eclipse-compiler` (2.8.0-01) both times, and while there are some minor differences, the bytecode still has all the dynamic "bloat" in it. The Groovy dependency I'm pulling in is 2.3.2, and I have my Java targets set at 1.7.

Is it expected for even an entire class marked `@CompileStatic` to have all of the Groovy metadata and -code compiled into it? If so, is there some other way to disable that?

Comment: A wild guess: i think groovy objects still retain meta capabilities for interoperability with other dynamic code. Out of curiosity: is the enhanced class size a problem?

Comment: @WillP Not specifically yet, but if I'm going to be using this pattern for command objects that will have large numbers of short-lived instances, I'd rather avoid the overhead if possible. Additionally, this makes the class disassembly a whole lot more difficult to read (up from 9 opcodes in pure Java to about 4 pages in Groovy).

Comment: I see. Did you pulled any benchmark? And... Why do you disassemble classes?

Comment: @WillP No benchmark yet. And for a number of reasons, primarily debugging, and including figuring out how some of the Spring AOP bits work.

Comment: I think this is something you should post in the [groovy mailing list](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but you can use `@CompileDynamic` any method inside a class annotated with `@CompileStatic` and it will be evaluated dynamically instead.